# nginx: [emerg] could not build referer_hash, you should increase referer_hash_bucket_size: 64

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

Good Day,

I am a novice to php and i am trying to run the livehelperchat open source code(https://livehelperchat.com/) in my ubuntu-16.04 instance and I have Nginx as default server listening port 80 and also php 5.6 running.

/var/www/html/sites-enabled/default

```
        server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name xxxxxxxxx;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/www/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

I can visit php info page in my web browser by visiting my server's domain name or public IP address followed by /info.php

I have my code at /var/www/html/livehelperchat/
I have fallowed the below link to set up the project in nginx
https://livehelperchat.com/nginx-configuration-tips-132a.html

/var/www/html/sites-enabled/example.conf

```
       server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
        root           /var/www/html/livehelperchat;
        location ~* (^(?!(?:(?!(php)).)*/(albums|bin|var|lib|cache|doc|settings|pos|modules)/).*?(index\.php|upgrade\.php)$) {
            include        /etc/nginx/livehelperchat_fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO  $query_string;
           # fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/livehelperchat/$fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
        #Allow hotlinking to normal and thumb size images
        location ~* (normal_|thumb_|^/design|^/cache|^/var/storagetheme)(.*)\.(gif|jpe?g?|png|mp3|svg|otf|woff|eot|ttf|ogg|wav|bmp|htm|swf|css|js|swf|pdf|ico)$ {
            ## @todo: add expires headers...
            # favicon is only stored in 1 dir, the design one; But browsers ask for it in the root
            if ($http_user_agent ~* "(WebReaper|wget|SiteSucker|SuperBot|Mihov Picture Downloader|TALWinHttpClient|A1 Website Download|WebCopier|Download Ninja|Microsoft URL Control|GetRight|Arachmo|MJ12bot|Gaisbot|Anonymous|Yanga|Twiceler|psbot|Irvine|Indy Library|HTTrack)" ) {
                return 403;
            }
            if ($http_referer ~* (stockingteensex.info|cbox.ws|teensos.net|dpstream.net|tagged.com|kaskus.us|gorilladatingservice.info|taringa.net|discuss.com|craigslist.org|poringa.net)) {
                return 403;
            }
            #sendfile off;
            #aio on;
            directio 512;
            expires max;
            access_log off;
             root           /var/www/html/livehelperchat;
        }
        # Do not allow to hotlink full size images except our self and major search engines
        location ~* \.(gif|jpe?g?|png|bmp|swf|css|js|svg|otf|eot|ttf|woff|swf|mp3|ogg|wav|pdf|ico|txt)$ {
            ## @todo: add expires headers...
            valid_referers none blocked server_names ~(livehelperchat.com|google.|reddit.|bing.|yahoo.);
            if ($invalid_referer) {
                return 403;
            }
            if ($http_user_agent ~* "(WebReaper|wget|SiteSucker|SuperBot|Mihov Picture Downloader|TALWinHttpClient|A1 Website Download|WebCopier|Download Ninja|Microsoft URL Control|GetRight|Arachmo|MJ12bot|Gaisbot|Anonymous|Yanga|Twiceler|psbot|Irvine|Indy Library|HTTrack)" ) {
                return 403;
            }
            if ($http_referer ~* (stockingteensex.info|cbox.ws|teensos.net|dpstream.net|tagged.com|kaskus.us|gorilladatingservice.info|taringa.net|discuss.com|craigslist.org|poringa.net)) {
                return 403;
            }
            #sendfile off;
            #aio on;
            directio 512;
            expires max;
             root           /var/www/html/livehelperchat;
        }
        location / {
            rewrite "^(.*)$" "/index.php?$1" last;
        }
    }
```

Now I am getting an error on doing **nginx -t**

```
nginx: [emerg] could not build referer_hash, you should increase referer_hash_bucket_size: 64
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

**service nginx restart**

Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**systemctl status nginx.service**

```
        nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
           Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
           Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-04-22 10:15:40 UTC; 1min 14s ago
          Process: 24237 ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          Process: 24232 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry TERM/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
          Process: 24111 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          Process: 31591 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
         Main PID: 24134 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

        Apr 22 10:15:40 ip-172-31-28-209 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
        Apr 22 10:15:40 ip-172-31-28-209 nginx[31591]: nginx: [emerg] could not build referer_hash, you should increase referer_hash_bucket_si
        Apr 22 10:15:40 ip-172-31-28-209 nginx[31591]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
        Apr 22 10:15:40 ip-172-31-28-209 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
        Apr 22 10:15:40 ip-172-31-28-209 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
        Apr 22 10:15:40 ip-172-31-28-209 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
        Apr 22 10:15:40 ip-172-31-28-209 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Any Help is Highly Appreciated. Thanks in Advance**

Comment: did you icrease the [`referer_hash_bucket_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#referer_hash_bucket_size)? For example `referer_hash_bucket_size 128;` in the `location`/`server` block where the `valid_referers` specified.

Comment: @Deadooshka,Thank you for the quick response. I am pretty new to Linux,so can you please let me know the path of directory where i can change the referer_hash_bucket_size to 128

Comment: it is about Nginx config. The path is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as I see in the log.

Comment: @Deadooshka,thank you for your time.I have tried adding 
referer_hash_bucket_size 128; in nginx.conf file and I got the fallowing error:

nginx: [emerg] "referer_hash_bucket_size" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:24
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Answer (score -2):

Must be a bug of Plesk, there is no way anymore to change the values also as the support told me.

I need to reinstall the server.

Comment: You want to re-install a complete server, because you have issues with a software package? Well... o.k.... that's up to you. A server administrator would normally re-install the depending software package, if he/she isn't able to investigate and fix the issue. ;-) Apart from that, just consider to investigate, if your nginx - version has been compiled with the "ngx_http_referer_module", before you try to add "referer_hash_bucket_size 128;" ( or something similar to this possible setting). Command to use: "nginx -V"